# python snake generate 7 direction based on head position

Tags: python

Let me explain myself.
I'm actually tring to create an AI for the game Snake. As input i would like to use distance from wall, distance from apple, distance from self for 7 different direction based on the head orientation.

Right now i have this code:

```
head_position = self.__snake.position[0]
front_direction_vector = numpy.array(self.__snake.position[0]) - numpy.array(self.__snake.position[1])
left_direction_vector = numpy.array([front_direction_vector[1], -front_direction_vector[0]])
right_direction_vector = numpy.array([-front_direction_vector[1], front_direction_vector[0]])
front_left_direction_vector = numpy.array([left_direction_vector[0], front_direction_vector[1]])
front_right_direction_vector = numpy.array([right_direction_vector[0], front_direction_vector[1]])
back_left_direction_vector = numpy.array([left_direction_vector[0], -front_direction_vector[1]])
back_right_direction_vector = numpy.array([right_direction_vector[0], -front_direction_vector[1]])
for i in range(1, 5):
    for direction in [front_direction_vector, left_direction_vector, right_direction_vector,
                      front_left_direction_vector, front_right_direction_vector, back_left_direction_vector,
                      back_right_direction_vector]:
        pos = head_position + direction * i
        pygame.draw.rect(self.__display, config.SNAKE_SENSOR_COLOR,
                         pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], self.__side[0] - 1, self.__side[1] - 1))
```

Works fine, but only when the snake is heading up or down. When the snake is looking right or left half of the "sensors" are gone and seems like i can't find a solution.

I will post 2 screenshot that show the problem.

[image: Working fine]
[image: Not working]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found the solution after hitting the wall for a while.
This is the working code

```
head_position = self.__snake.position[0]
front_direction_vector = self.__snake.position[0] - self.__snake.position[1]
left_direction_vector = numpy.array([front_direction_vector[1], -front_direction_vector[0]])
right_direction_vector = numpy.array([-front_direction_vector[1], front_direction_vector[0]])
back_direction_vector = numpy.array([-front_direction_vector[0], -front_direction_vector[1]])
front_left_direction_vector = front_direction_vector - right_direction_vector
front_right_direction_vector = front_direction_vector - left_direction_vector
back_left_direction_vector = back_direction_vector - right_direction_vector
back_right_direction_vector = back_direction_vector - left_direction_vector
for i in range(1, 5):
    for direction in [front_direction_vector, left_direction_vector, right_direction_vector,
                      front_left_direction_vector, front_right_direction_vector, back_direction_vector, back_right_direction_vector, back_left_direction_vector
                      ]:
        pos = head_position + direction * i
        pygame.draw.rect(self.__display, config.SNAKE_SENSOR_COLOR,
                         pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], self.__side[0] - 1, self.__side[1] - 1))
```